# Reading Text files and Skipping rows if not integer values

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, graph, text-files

I am trying to read values out of a very long text file (2552 lines) inputting various columns of the file into different arrays. I want to later use these values to plot a graph using the data from the file. However, not all the rows in a column are integers (eg"<1.6" instead of "1.6") and some of the rows are blank.

Is there a way to skip over these rows which are blank completely or hold non-integer values without skipping a value in my array? (and hence find out how long my arrays need to be in the first place to remove excess zeros at the end)

Here is my code so far:

```
# Light curve plot


jul_day = np.zeros(2551)
mag = np.zeros(2551)
mag_err = np.zeros(2551)


file = open("total_data.txt")
lines = file.readlines()[1:]


i = 0

for line in lines:
    fields = line.split(",")
    jul_day[i] = float(fields[0])
    mag[i] = float(fields[1])
    mag_err[i] = float(fields[2])


    i = i + 1
```

Here is an example of an error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d091536c6666> in <module>()
     18     fields = line.split(",")
     19     jul_day[i] = float(fields[0])
---> 20     mag[i] = float(fields[1])
     21     #mag_err[i] = float(fields[2])
     22 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '<1.6'
```

Comment: umm... have you tried something like: `jul_day, mag, mag_err = np.genfromtxt('total_data.txt', delimiter=',', skip_header=1, usecols=[0, 1, 2], invalid_raise=False, unpack=True)` ?

Comment: This has seemed to work, however, the graph plotted does not look anything like expected, but I do not get any error messages so the code seems to be fine. Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the arrays then and see if they individually make sense against the input... you may want to do something regarding NaNs...

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is good for discerning types.

You could insert the logic to determine if a value is, indeed, an integer prior to casting it. For instance:

```
if isinstance(fields[1], int):
    mag[i] = float(fields[1])
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also [remove unwanted characters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-removing-unwanted-characters-from-string/) from your string prior to casting. This should eliminate the ValueError in your example above.

Comment: Since the OP is reading lines as text, after they've split them, then all those elements are still strings... so the `isinstance` can never be true...

Comment: I caught that right after I made the comment--oops! Nonetheless, removing unwanted characters should resolve the issue.

Comment: Perhaps - perhaps not... Maybe making `<1.6` into what can be a valid float of `1.6` is incorrect and is going to skew the data...

Comment: In some of the rows of the columns, there is no value at all. i.e. no string or integer. I would like to be able to either skip these rows completely or assign them a value of zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use isinstance() to make sure the type is a int:

```
for line in lines:
    fields = line.split(",")
    jul_day[i] = float(fields[0])
    if isinstance(fields[1],int):
        mag[i] = float(fields[1])
    if isinstance(fields[2],int):
        mag_err[i] = float(fields[2])
```

Comment: As Jon Clements had mentioned earlier, isinstance would always return false for string values. Unless you removed special characters and casted them beforehand, but that would make calling isinstance pointless.

Comment: If it were to come back false for string values, is there a way to skip to the next line without skipping a value in the array?